# Redirect if Invalid id is given

Tags: ember.js, router

I have the following Routes

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gradebooks', function() {
    this.resource('gradebook', { path: ':gradebook_id' });
  });
});

App.GradebooksRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('gradebook');
  }
});

App.GradebookRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var id = params.gradebook_id;
    var gradebook = this.store.find('gradebook', id);
    var self = this;
    gradebook.then(null, function(reason) {
      self.transitionTo('gradebooks');
    });
    return gradebook; 
  }
})
```

Templates:

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}

  <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
    {{#link-to "gradebook" this}}
      {{title}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>

  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

It's works fine and dandy except when an invalid id is given. (ex. `#/gradebooks/invalid_id`).

Currently, the redirection works great (I do get the error `Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, but it still redirects. However, the resulting list of gradebooks has the invalid gradebook in the list.

If I manually navigate to `#/gradebooks/invalid_id_1`, `#/gradebooks/invalid_id_2`, `#/gradebooks/invalid_id_3`, etc., the invalid gradebook gets added to the list of gradebooks every time.

Any ideas why? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `App.GradebooksGradeBookRoute` and not `App.GradebookRoute`?

Comment: I tried it with `App.GradeboosGradebookRoute` and they both work.

Comment: I believe you need to use the afterModel hook. See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

instead of manually handling the find model promise its better to let ember do it, it will trigger an error event if the find 
promise is rejected

```js
App.GradebookRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var id = params.gradebook_id;
    return this.store.find('gradebook', id);
  },
  actions: {
    error: function(reason) {
      alert(reason); // "FAIL"

      // Can transition to another route here, e.g.
      // transitionTo('gradebooks');

      // Uncomment the line below to bubble this error event:
      // return true;
    }
})
```

more info http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/